# VideoView displaying online streams

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-video-player

I m trying to write an app. And i need to do Activity to watch online streams. For now trying with youtube. And i`v got error:/

This i code:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Log.d(TAG, "Starting Video View");

    setContentView(R.layout.video_views);

    this.Url = getIntent().getStringExtra("Url");
    Log.d(TAG, "Stream Address: " + Url);

    video_view = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.video_views);
    Uri uri = Uri.parse(Url);

    video_view.setVideoURI(uri);
    video_view.requestFocus();
    video_view.start();

}
```

And here is error:

```
04-17 09:16:07.151: D/MediaPlayer(26908): Couldn't open file on client side, trying server side
04-17 09:16:30.250: E/MediaPlayer(26908): error (1, -2147483648)
04-17 09:16:30.250: E/MediaPlayer(26908): Error (1,-2147483648)
04-17 09:16:30.250: D/VideoView(26908): Error: 1,-2147483648
```

Url is for 100% correct and i cant open it in my browser. Any ideas? I m trying to open only on emulator, can it be source of issue?